# Does the Google Drive App create a folder that syncs automatically?

Tags: cloud, google-drive

On my computer I have a Google Drive folder that syncs to the cloud.

Is there a folder like that on my android phone after installing Google Drive?

The idea would be to make a 'photos' folder in there and save all my photos from the camera in that folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe this is the way Google Drive works. The app, if I am not mistaken, allows you to view (and edit some Google documents) but maintains them in the cloud. While it does allow you to download them, it saves them to your Download folder for local use only.

You can choose photos you've taken from your gallery and upload them to Google Drive, but (if I am not mistaken), there is no automatic folder syncing option.

You can use [Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus&hl=en) though. It automatically adds all your photos to a Google+ album only you can see. Given, not as easy as Drive, but still a good auto-upload option. I don't know of an easy way to get them from there to a Drive folder though :/

> You can also use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full). It could sync folders with Google
>   Docs, and still works after Docs upgraded to Drive, Google Drive is
>   fully supported. Just choose Google Docs when adding account in the
>   app. In case, you don't want to pay, its [free lite version][3 is also
>   in Play Store, but with some limitations.

Thanks for the above goes to [Sachin Shekhar](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3303/sachin-shekhar).

Comment: interesting. i also saw this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22614/google-drive-directory-syncronisation do you have any experience with that app?

Comment: I don't, but it looks like a good choice! I'll add it to my answer here.

Comment: @mkoryak I do have experience with it. Google Drive on Windows has some issues, but this one is perfect. I haven't encountered any bug yet. Once, my deletion wasn't going under sync and app always downloaded deleted files. So, I contacted developer. He responded quickly. It wasn't a bug, but a setting glitch.